# Access Live Stream with Raspberry Pi Camera Module on Web Browser using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, raspberry-pi, mpeg

I am building a time-lapse camera web application using Raspberry Pi and the Raspberry Pi Camera Module. So far I have built a web application (using NodeJS, Express, AngularJS, and BootStrap 3) that can interact with the Raspberry Camera Module using an open source NodeJS module (https://www.npmjs.org/package/raspicam). My web app can set time-lapse settings and take photos by pushing the buttons on the web interface. However, it currently does not have a live stream feature on the web browser where users can watch what the Raspberry Pi Camera module is seeing remotely. I would love to figure out a way to display a live stream of the camera module on the web by simply doing something like this in the html file:

```
<img src="live-stream-raspberry-pi-camera">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I came up with for live streaming from a camera. It's crude but it works in all browsers.

I don't know how you access the Raspberry pi camera but the example below shows how to access a built-in web cam in linux:

Encode your camera to a updateing image file with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 0 -i /dev/video0 -update 1 -q 1 -r 5 -y /video/feed/1.jpg
```

Read the image file with php and output contents on change:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_write_close();
$imgFile = '/video/feed/1.jpg';
$img = (file_get_contents($imgFile));
$lastImgSize = $_SESSION['imageSize'];
while (true) {
    usleep(20000);
    $img = (file_get_contents($imgFile));
    $imgSize = strlen($img);
    if ($lastImgSize != $imgSize) {
        break;
    }
} 
session_start();
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
$_SESSION['imageSize'] = $imgSize;
echo $img;
exit;
```

Reload the image with javascript, the php will deliver a new image when available:

```
<img id="feed" src>
        <script>
            img = new Image
            function f() {
                img.src = "img.php?rnd=" + Date.now();
                img.onload = function() {
                    feed.src = img.src;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        f();
                    }, 50);
                };
                img.onerror = function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        f();
                    }, 50);
                };
            }
            f();
        </script>
```

If you're looking for something a bit fancier:

Take a look at [flowplayer](http://demos.flowplayer.org/basics/live.html) which supports live streaming from a rtmp / hls source, both can be encoded with ffmpeg.

Or fancier still [Dashcast](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/dashcast/) a linux / windows streaming service which encodes live streams in the html5 [mpeg-DASH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) format currently supported by ie and chrome, firefox support is [on the way](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Platform/MediaSourceExtensions)

Answer (score 0):

For something that simple you could send a multipart/x-mixed-replace response where each part is a frame of video. Chrome and Firefox removed support for this type of response when used with XMLHttpRequest, but AFAIK they are still allowed for image elements.